# How to eliminate the first delay in playing video in ionic

Tags: video, ionic-framework, delay

I am trying to play a video inside the `ion-content` tags.

**Issues:**

1. The video takes some time to play. In this time it shows a dark screen.
2. After few minutes the video will play.

**Question:**

How do I avoid the first delay time and play the video when the user opens the app?

**Code:**

```
   <ion-content>
     <video  id='play_video' controls="controls"  width="100%" height="100%"    preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer">
     <source id='mp4Source' src="http://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/17411365_1330668097014253_7208742851285352448_n.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
     </video>
    </ion-content>
```

Comment: hey did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the video is taking this much time to play it is quite likely a server side issue.

The most common issue is the part of the video file which contains the Metadata being at the end of the file rater than the start in mp4 files.

This means the client cannot play the video until it has downloaded the whole video.

There is a common technique to move the Metadata 'block' or 'atom' to the start.

More info here (take a look at delivery setup):

- https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/mp4box/

and here:

- https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart

Usage is very simple - for example with qtfaststart:

> $ bin/qtfaststart infile [outfile]